# Returned data type from a numeric expression in query

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

In cloudera's Impala Guide (
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_conversion_functions.html) there's an example that demonstrates the use of typeof() function to check the returned data type of a numeric expression:

```
+--------------------------+
| typeof(5.30001 / 2342.1) |
+--------------------------+
| DECIMAL(13,11)           |
+--------------------------+
```

When I do :

```
select typeof(5.30001),typeof(2342.1),typeof(5.30001 / 2342.1);
```

What it gives is something like this

```
DECIMAL(6,5)    DECIMAL(5,1)    DECIMAL(13,11)
```

I mean the first two are obvious but I have no idea why the data type for the 3rd one is like that.Can the returned data type be determined from the numeric expression itself? Also, for columns division expressions which I represent as  `decimal(13,5)/decimal(25,4)`(e.g.) is there a way to determine what the returned data type should be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bit obscure. Here is the related code doing arithmetic decimal type conversions.

```
  /**
   * Returns the result type for (t1 op t2) where t1 and t2 are both DECIMAL, used when
   * DECIMAL version 2 is enabled.
   *
   * These rules are similar to (post Dec 2016) Hive / sql server rules.
   * http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx
   * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx
   *
   * TODO: implement V2 rules for ADD/SUB.
   *
   * Changes:
   *  - There are slight difference with how precision/scale reduction occurs compared
   *    to SQL server when the desired precision is more than the maximum supported
   *    precision.  But an algorithm of reducing scale to a minimum of 6 is used.
   */
  private static ScalarType getDecimalArithmeticResultTypeV2(Type t1, Type t2,
      ArithmeticExpr.Operator op) throws AnalysisException {
    Preconditions.checkState(t1.isFullySpecifiedDecimal());
    Preconditions.checkState(t2.isFullySpecifiedDecimal());
    ScalarType st1 = (ScalarType) t1;
    ScalarType st2 = (ScalarType) t2;
    int s1 = st1.decimalScale();
    int s2 = st2.decimalScale();
    int p1 = st1.decimalPrecision();
    int p2 = st2.decimalPrecision();
    int resultScale;
    int resultPrecision;

    switch (op) {
      case DIVIDE:
        // Divide result always gets at least MIN_ADJUSTED_SCALE decimal places.
        resultScale = Math.max(ScalarType.MIN_ADJUSTED_SCALE, s1 + p2 + 1);
        resultPrecision = p1 - s1 + s2 + resultScale;
        break;
      case MOD:
        resultScale = Math.max(s1, s2);
        resultPrecision = Math.min(p1 - s1, p2 - s2) + resultScale;
        break;
      case MULTIPLY:
        resultScale = s1 + s2;
        resultPrecision = p1 + p2 + 1;
        break;
      case ADD:
      case SUBTRACT:
      default:
        // Not yet implemented - fall back to V1 rules.
        return getDecimalArithmeticResultTypeV1(t1, t2, op);
    }
    // Use the scale reduction technique when resultPrecision is too large.
    return ScalarType.createAdjustedDecimalType(resultPrecision, resultScale);
  }
```

So 5.30001 is of precision 6 and scale 5, and 2342.1 precision 5 and scale 1. We have s1 = 5 and p2 = 5. The output scale is of s1 + p2 + 1 == 11, and precision is 6 - 5 + 1 + 11 == 13  . These rules are better explained in the comment links.